# Problems related to Sets and Mappings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transformation

I have a problem which is related to Sets and Mappings. For details:

Given a mapping: $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $A \subset X$. The following conclusion is true or not? Why?
$$
f(X) \backslash f(A) \subset f(X\backslash A)
$$
I thought that this problem could be solved by using element principle, which means that using $x$ belongs to one side and prove the other but I failed. I really need your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $y\in f(X)\setminus f(A)$, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Can it happen that $x\in A$?

> No: if $x\in A$, then $y=f(x)$ would be in $f(A)$, contradicting the hypothesis $y\notin f(A)$.
>  So the answer on the original question is affirmative.

Comment: It can be easy to prove the if-statement but I still don't understand the way to prove it

Comment: You mean to prove what? That $y=f(x)$ for some $x$? That's by definition of $f(X)$. Knowing that $y\notin f(A)$, can (any of) this $x$ be in $A$?

Comment: Can you give me the full answer? I think your question "Can it happen to ..." can be answered by "Yes" but I am not sure

Comment: No, it can't happen.

Comment: So please give me your answer, I'm so confused here :((

Comment: I updated my answer.